# how to fix the header with content above it so that content above the header remains hidden on scroll

Tags: html, css

please refer to this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/v7gf7/2/

I want that when one scroll the page the content that goes above the header(green background) 
should not be visible.

Here's my html as given the fiddle:

```
<div class="main-container clearfix">
    <div class="dummy">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Reprehenderit nam  amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Soluta, quibusdam modi magni ratione.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Rem, at, ipsa, harum vitae dignissimos veniam veritatis consectetur aperiam accusamus quisquam libero alias ipsam recusandae dolorum dolorem id porro tempora sapiente?consequatur quos nesciunt mollitia nam odit impedit id consectetur vel.
    </div>
    <div class="table clearfix">
        <div class="row header">
            Header
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="cell">Name</div>
            <div class="cell">Name</div>
            <div class="cell">Name</div>
            <div class="cell">Name</div>
            <div class="cell">Name</div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="cell">Name</div>
            <div class="cell">Name</div>
            <div class="cell">Name</div>
            <div class="cell">Name</div>
            <div class="cell">Name</div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="cell">Name</div>
            <div class="cell">Name</div>
            <div class="cell">Name</div>
            <div class="cell">Name</div>
            <div class="cell">Name</div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="cell">Name</div>
            <div class="cell">Name</div>
            <div class="cell">Name</div>
            <div class="cell">Name</div>
            <div class="cell">Name</div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="cell">Name</div>
            <div class="cell">Name</div>
            <div class="cell">Name</div>
            <div class="cell">Name</div>
            <div class="cell">Name</div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="cell">Name</div>
            <div class="cell">Name</div>
            <div class="cell">Name</div>
            <div class="cell">Name</div>
            <div class="cell">Name</div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="cell">Name</div>
            <div class="cell">Name</div>
            <div class="cell">Name</div>
            <div class="cell">Name</div>
            <div class="cell">Name</div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="cell">Name</div>
            <div class="cell">Name</div>
            <div class="cell">Name</div>
            <div class="cell">Name</div>
            <div class="cell">Name</div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="cell">Name</div>
            <div class="cell">Name</div>
            <div class="cell">Name</div>
            <div class="cell">Name</div>
            <div class="cell">Name</div>
        </div>

    </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: As I know, you have to use `javascript` to control scroll events

Answer (score 0):

If the lorem ipsum isn't required before the header, then you could simply add a plain white block above the header and stick it. [`http://jsfiddle.net/v7gf7/4/`](http://jsfiddle.net/v7gf7/4/)

If the lorem ipsum is required, then I'd probably make a white block and hide it in the content box, under the header. then use `https://github.com/davist11/jQuery-Stickem` to make it become active on scroll, [example here](http://davist11.github.io/jQuery-Stickem/).

Comment: well, the javascript option is always there..but it would have been nice if there was any css way for doing it.